# Debugging Cucumber step definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

Is there a way of stopping execution of a step definition in order to examine the values of instance variables? Maybe debugger, but that didn't work when I tried it just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugger will work. You need to require ruby-debug either with `require 'ruby-debug'` or by passing the -d option to the cucumber executable.

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried requiring it in my step definition, adding debugger keyword, and then ran the cucumber executable, both with and without -d option, but debugger didn't kick in.

Comment: Ah, I think it was because I was using spork. Taking out --drb flag solved it.